# Gmail & Filters

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, sorting

I have set up filters in Gmail to attach a label to specific emails and have checked the box marked "skip inbox/put in the archive".  However, some emails get marked with the correct label but still show up in the inbox - how do I keep these from going to the inbox?

Comment: > However, some emails get marked with the correct label but still show up in the inbox - how do I keep these from going to the inbox? That shouldn't be happening. I have over 100 filters with `skip inbox/put in the archive` activated and I never encountered that issue. Try to see what's in common with "some emails" to understand the issue. Post a screenshot of all your filters if you need people here to help debug.